# Moving multiple Turtles in Python 3.4.3 to make a "Tusi Couple"?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there a way to make `multiple` turtles move at the `same time`? (Or at least so it seems like it)

I'm trying to make a `"tusi couple"` (look up a `GIF` if you don't know what it is) using Turtle in `Python 3.4.3`. However i'm not too sure how I could make multiple turtles move `smoothly` at the `same time.`

I have already tried making my turtles move `in turn` and pretty much in every way I can come up with, even tried to merge several of these subroutines, but everything I tried compromises `smoothness` or `speed`, or it doesn't work

Here is my `initial code` that I began to work with:

```
import turtle
def dot1():
    p1, p2 = turtle.Turtle(), turtle.Turtle()
    p1.goto(-300,0) #p = point
    p2.goto(300,0)
    c1, c2 = p1.position(), p2.position() #c = coordinate
    dot = turtle.Turtle()
    p1.penup()
    p2.penup()
    p1.shape("circle")
    p2.shape("circle")
    dot.shape("circle")
    dot.turtlesize(3)

    dot.penup()
    dot.hideturtle()
    dot.goto(c1)
    dot.showturtle()
    dot.speed(0)

    dot.setheading(dot.towards(c2)) #Towards second dot
    while dot.distance(c2) > 6:
        if dot.distance(c1) <300:
            dot.fd((dot.distance(c1)+0.1)/30)
        else:
            dot.fd(dot.distance(c2)/30)

    dot.setheading(dot.towards(c1)) #Towards first dot
    while dot.distance(c1) > 6:
        if dot.distance(c1) >300:
            dot.fd((dot.distance(c2)+0.1)/30) 
        else:
            dot.fd(dot.distance(c1)/30)
dot1()
```

From this you can tell I want to make `multiple copies` of this subroutine to run but `at different angles`. The `minimum being 3` of these turtles.

I'm fairly new to python in general so if this is some simple problem to fix then please just give me a `tip` as to what I should look into, if the solution is simple/comprehensible then I don't want the `entire thing` done for me.

This was definitely a fun challenge until I realised i'm clueless as to how to make this work.

Thanks for any help.

edit: best if you see this GIF: http://intothecontinuum.tumblr.com/post/57654628209/each-of-the-white-circles-are-really-just-moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python turtle is admitedly no speed demon when it comes to animation.  The trick to getting any speed out of it is to take the time to understand how it works and ask it to do as little as possible.  Below is my implementation of your 'each-of-the-white-circles-are-really-just-moving' animated GIF image:

```
from math import pi, cos
from itertools import cycle
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CIRCLES = 8
DIAMETER = 300
RADIUS = DIAMETER / 2

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.dot(DIAMETER + CURSOR_SIZE)

turtles = []

for n in range(CIRCLES):
    angle = n * pi / CIRCLES

    circle = Turtle('circle')
    circle.radians()
    circle.color('red')
    circle.penup()

    circle.setheading(angle)  # this stays fixed

    # stash a couple of our values with the turtle
    circle.angle = angle  # this will change
    circle.sign = 1 if cos(angle) > 0 else -1

    turtles.append(circle)

circles = cycle(turtles)

while True:  # really should use timer event but we're going for maximum speed!
    circle = next(circles)

    cosine = cos(circle.angle)
    circle.forward(cosine * RADIUS - circle.sign * circle.distance(0, 0))

    # update the values we stashed with the turtle
    circle.sign = 1 if cosine > 0 else -1
    circle.angle -= 0.1

    screen.update()

screen.tracer(True)
screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

If you want to see the lines on which the circles are moving back and forth, then add the following code just before the `turtles = []` line:

```
turtle.radians()
turtle.color('white')
for n in range(CIRCLES):
    turtle.setheading(n * pi / CIRCLES)
    turtle.forward(RADIUS)
    turtle.backward(DIAMETER)
    turtle.forward(RADIUS)
```